# Merge two databases with the missing contents

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have recently migrated one website to a new linux server. But we imported the database of the website was 7days old the actual thing. Now 4 days gone after the migration. So these 4 days database updates which was wriiten to the new server that contains the contents of old server database. We just forget about the 7days database updates from the old server at the time of dns change.

But now our website is having a big issue because they didnt have the missing 7 days database contents. if we imported old database from old server to new server then our latest 4 days database updates on new server will go. Iam in the middle of this.

Can you please suggest a better way to merge these databases into one without any issues or overwritten, so that we can update the same to new server then only the site will run fine. In short we need to merge two databases with the missing contents and site should work fine also. Help me please.

Comment: all the master table with a unique column can be updated with INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Comment: Can u please explain in detail. I am totally a new bie in mysql

Answer (score 0):

This is going to depend a lot on your data structure (how many auto_increment fields you have, foreign keys, etc.).  You will need to dump out everything that was added to the database after the export but prior to the migration, then find a way to import each record.

What is stored in the database?

Comment: It contains tables only. But i am a new bie in mysql structure. Is there any easy method to merge these contents

Comment: I mean, what's in the tables? How are the keys and indexes structured? That's the problem. Say you had a table `employees` with unique ids 1, 2, and 3 pre-export. Between the export and the migration, someone added employee 4. But another employee was added _after_ migration. Now, the old database and the new database each have employee 4, but they're not the same. You have to import every such employee (the ones created post-export, pre-migration). You will also have to re-index related data (like a `performance_reviews` table, for example). It's going to be a lot of work, honestly.